How to merge some changes from one Git repository to another?
I have a repository in Azure that on some points (multiple times) I need to merge from my repository to one that a client has permission (also mine in my Azure).
The client wants to have the code to make some changes along the development but i dont want to give permission over my repo, only to certain branch and having the possibility to still make the client its own branches and changes.
Whats the best way to achieve this?
2 repos, git submodules, some permission config on Azure or something else?
edit: To clarify here is some graph of what i need.


The reasonable best pratice would be:

The client forks your repo.
The client creates new branch.
The client issues a push with its changes into the above branch.
The client sends you a merge/pull request.
You review the changes, checking the code and selected target branch (the one you expect to be addressed by the client).
You approve/reject changes into your repo.

Edit:
Instead, if you want to push your changes to the client repo:

Add on your client side the client remote by git remote add client-remote <client-remote-url>.
Create a branch where you merge onto the commits you want for your client.
Push the above branch toward your client by git push client-remote.


I added a edit of other specs but i dont want the client changes. I only want to "deploy" my changes to its repo/branch

Ok I understand now. I added some other info.
